# Normal map from height map artifact

Tags: opengl, webgl, shader, normals, heightmap

I'm baking normal map on the fragment shader from a height map. The height map looks great and looks smooth. However, when I generate the normal map I get very weird result.

Here are two rendered images that show the problem, one with all lighting calculations and second one has the normal map image applied on top of the mesh.
[image: Normap map]

[image]

The way I bake the normal map is by sampling neighbor pixels on the fragment shader.

The mesh is 32x32 and the normal map and height map is 64x64. Here's the fragment shader code that samples the neighbor pixels:

```
float NORMAL_OFF = (1.0 / 64.0);
vec3 off = vec3(-NORMAL_OFF, 0, NORMAL_OFF);

// s11 = Current
float s11 = texture2D(uSampler, texturePos).x;

// s01 = Left
float s01 = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(texturePos.xy + off.xy)).x;

// s21 = Right
float s21 = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(texturePos.xy + off.zy)).x;

// s10 = Below
float s10 = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(texturePos.xy + off.yx)).x;

// s12 = Above
float s12 = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(texturePos.xy + off.yz)).x;

vec3 va = normalize( vec3(off.z, 0.0, s21 - s11) );
vec3 vb = normalize( vec3(0.0, off.z, s12 - s11) );

vec3 normal = normalize( cross(va, vb) );
```

texturePos is calculated on the vertex shader as vertexPosition.x / 128 (128 because the distance between vertices is 4 pixels. So 32 * 4 = 128).

Why is my result so weird?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your height map has too few sampling depth resolution, resulting in those hard steps. Probably your height map is 8 bit, giving you a max of 256 height levels. Now if your height map is is higher planar resolution than 256, the lateral resolution is insufficient to represent a smooth heightfield.

Solution: Use a higher sampling resolution for your height map. 16 bits are a popular choice.

Your shader and baking code are fine though, they just don't get input data with enough resolution to work with.

Comment: Thanks! When I was rendering the height map to my framebuffer I was using gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE instead of gl.FLOAT. That seemed to fix it :-)

Comment: @raRaRa: You might want to use GL_R16 as internal format as well (OpenGL-3 and later). Depending on your GPU/driver combination it might yield better or worse performance than GL_FLOAT. Only way to know it for sure is to benchmark.

Comment: @raRaRa: Also consider using GL_R16F. It gives floating-point precision, but without the size of full-on GL_R32F.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Floating point does not really increase precision (in fact, half float offers only 12 bits of precision) but a wider value range, where the precision scales inversely to the order of magnitude of the value. In some applications this is undesireable.

Comment: FYI - I'm using WebGL thus I can't use GL_R16 nor GL_R16F. I need to stick with GL_FLOAT for now.